# CSS Align all li items in single row

Tags: html, css

in `li` i have some element such as `img` and `a` and i want to align all of this items in single row. but i can not do that. for example you can see [ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0juxj7qn/)

my html:

```
<div class="" id="menu_section">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><img src="imgs/verify.png"><a href="#firstPage">First Slide</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second Slide</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my css:

```
#menu {
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#menu li.active {
    background: #666;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

#menu li.active a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#menu li:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#menu li a,
#menu li.active a {
    padding: 9px 18px;
    display: block;
}

#menu li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}

#menu_section {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 58px;
    z-index: 70;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: The li elements are showing horizontally instead of vertically.  Is the problem that the text ("first slide", "second slide") is stacked below the associated images instead of next to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to align them next to one another then float the `li` contents

```
#menu li > * {float: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the a element to display inline-block instead of block if you want them to appear side by side. Img elements by default display inline so this shouldn't need to be set.

https://jsfiddle.net/0juxj7qn/1/

```
#menu li a,
#menu li.active a {
    padding: 9px 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```